# play a wav file c# code

Tags: c#

How can I play a wav file to a another computer? I know i have to send the wav file as a buffer on the out device. Can someone give a short eq in c#?

Comment: Please stop asking different incarnations of the same question. Each new question adds more specifics that should have been added to this one.

Comment: What are you meaning with "play a wav file to a another computer"? I cant understand this phrase.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use Flash or Silverlight to play the audio in browser. You don't need to reinvent the wheel. Also you don't need to do much on server side other than hosting the wav or mp3 file, rest is done by the client plugin/player.

Comment: could you give me an example?