# c# .wav file over udp

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [c# capture microphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4942611/c-capture-microphone)
>   [play a wav file c# code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5066433/play-a-wav-file-c-code)

I need some examples with how to record and send a .wav file over udp. If I call a number i would like to hear this .wav file as response.

I have to play the wav sound in real time. I can do this by using udp socket,no?

Comment: Like an answering machine?  What does that have to do with UDP?

Comment: yes, it's like an answering machine. How can I do that?

Comment: A calls B. B response using the answering machine.

Comment: Please describe, what are you stucked with. Yes, you can send wav stream thru UDF, yes, you can play it on the client machine. What would you like to know? If you need some code examples, search the web, there are some.

Comment: You already asked that question multiple times. Just noticed that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4942611/c-capture-microphone/4943661#4943661 is one of *your* older questions. Asking the same question again using a new nick isn't nice. Looking over your accounts this is the *eight*'s time you ask such a question. Use a single question and add additional information instead.

Comment: Sounds to me like you'd be better off using Twilio or Tropo.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to send .wav files over the network? Compressing them before is usually a good idea. If you transmit speech the speex codec is good, for music you could use vorbis.

And why UDP? I'd start with TCP since it's easier to use, and only switch to UDP if really necessary. Typically UDP is better if you have significant packet loss, because you can simpy skip dropped packets. But normally packet loss is rather uncommon and TCP sufficies.

There are many similar questions. For example see this question: [c# capture microphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4942611/c-capture-microphone/4943661#4943661)

Comment: I need an answering machine connected with the microphone. (a calls b - b respond using an answering machien). How to do that? How can I connect the wav file to the microphone in order to send it to A?

Comment: Did you look at the codeproject example I linked last time?

Comment: I've tested the code from codeproject. If I use different ip's (besides 127.0.0.1) at the remote computer i can't hear clearly the wav file. Did you succeed to hear the wav clearly ?

Comment: I just can't find any other examples. I don't wanna use codecs like directx for eq.

Comment: If you don't like the codec they used, you could use speex or vorbis.

Comment: can you give me some links or examples?:). Do you know how to link a wav to the microphone?

Comment: I don't have an example for your exact use-case. But you should be able to put together the different parts of the solution. Else I'd code your program, and not you.

Comment: i need some ideas:). I am stuck. I don't know how to make a connection between a file and the microphone